# SQL INSERT INTO giving error without explanation; passed syntax test

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a modal form to capture complete contact information and upload to database. Worked perfectly. Used exact same code to create a second modal window to use for login. Eliminated excess code. Continue to get exact same error message:

> Error: INSERT INTO team_members (id, username, password) VALUES (NULL, 'hfuller', 'davidson')

I have created a testing file and it connects. I simply cannot update to the database. I even tried copying and pasting an instructor's example file. That file also failed to update database.

Here is my code (I changed database reference; everything else matched my database):

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

if( isset( $_POST["add"] ) ) {

    // build a function that validates data
    function validateFormData( $formData ) {
        $formData = trim( stripslashes( htmlspecialchars( $formData ) ) );
        return $formData;
    }

    // set all variables to empty by default
    $username = $password = "";

    // check to see if inputs are empty
    // create variables with form data
    // wrap the data with our function

    if( !$_POST["username"] ) {
        $nameError = "Please enter a username <br>";
    } else {
        $username = validateFormData( $_POST["username"] );
    }

    if( !$_POST["password"] ) {
        $passwordError = "Please enter a password <br>";
    } else {
        $password = validateFormData( $_POST["password"] );
    }


    // check to see if each variable has data
     if( $username && $password ) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO team_members (id, username, password)
        VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password')";

        if( mysqli_query( $conn, $query ) ) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'><span>&times;</span></button><strong>Credentials are authenticated!</strong> You can now proceed to do the great work that you do!</div>";
        } else {
            echo "Error: ". $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }

}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>



<!-- Modal for Request Information Packet -->
        <form class="modal fade form-horizontal" id="team_login" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ); ?>" method="post">            
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">            
                <div class="modal-content">                
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp;Login to the ICTUS Team Portal</h3>
                        <p>You must enter the correct username and password in order to open the ICTUS Team Member Portal.</p>            
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="center-block text-center">
                            <img class="img-thumbnail img-circle" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="Warning Sign"><br><br>
                            <p><strong>Just a reminder that the information included in the team portal is subject to our Confidentiality Agreement and cannot be shared without prior written permission. Thank you for your cooperation.</strong></p><br><br>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $nameError; ?>* <?php echo $passwordError; ?></small>Login Credentials: </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="information" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="information">Log In</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I know that this is not secure, etc. It is the first step in creating a secure login page that I am working on. I am just really stuck on the first page and cannot find the problem. Like I said, the more complex complete contact information collection form in a modal window works perfect.

Comment: Why do you insert null into ID? I think you want to keep the id out of this since it is probably auto increment?

Comment: what's error log? and why you're passing `NULL` in insert query id params every time? and what's the db table schema?

Comment: I hope I'd column is auto increment not null

Comment: The id is treated in the above code exactly as the template that was giving to me. It is set up in the database to auto increment. I have removed it as suggested; it did not solve the initial problem. It also worked in the first page I programmed (this is my second). It is my understanding that the "NULL" means nothing is being entered from the form.

Comment: Here is the database information: name of database: ictus; name of table: team_members; names of columns: ID, username, password. ID is set as an integer that auto increments; username and password are both set as varchar and cannot be null.

Comment: `'); DELETE ALL DATABASES` as the username will break your server. Where is the server right now so I can attack it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this query:

```
INSERT INTO team_members (id, username, password)
                VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password')
```

If `id` is meant to *identify* the record then `NULL` isn't going to do a very good job of that.  How would one identify any given record if *all* identifiers are `NULL`?  Also, if it's a primary key then it's likely to be `NOT NULL` *and* would need a unique value for any given row.

My *guess* is that `id` is an auto-incrementing column, or in some other way automatically generating its value in the database itself.  If that's the case, omit it from the query entirely:

```
INSERT INTO team_members (username, password)
                VALUES ('$username', '$password')
```

Basically, don't try to supply a value if the database is meant to create one itself.  The database will prioritize the one you supply over any attempt to create one.

---

As a side note, you may want to look into using prepared statements and query parameters.  Sanitizing input is a good thing, but it's still just covering up the underlying problem.  Which is that you're creating user input *as code* instead of *as a value*.  Using query parameters treats the input as a value and doesn't try to *execute* it.

Comment: I have removed the id and NULL reference. It did not solve my problem of updating the database.

Comment: @C.Fuller: In what way is it failing?  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  What error occurs?

Comment: First, I created a connection file and a testing file. This confirms that I can connect to the database and see the records inserted with PHP. I then attempted to complete the form using a MAMP server. I enter a username and a password that I want updated to the database. Instead of alerting that it has been successful, I get the error message exactly as stated in my initial question: Error: INSERT INTO team_members (id, username, password) VALUES (NULL, 'hfuller', 'davidson'). In this specific case, I attempted to add hfuller as the username and davidson as a password. It will not update.

Comment: The error message does not reference a line number or anything. I checked my PHP against a third-party syntax checker. It passed with no errors. I have coded it using Brackets.

Comment: @C.Fuller: What happens when you try to execute that same SQL manually?

Comment: David, I don't understand what you mean by execute manually? I can add records by inserting using PHPAdmin.

Comment: @C.Fuller: I mean that you need to debug this a little bit.  When the query fails, capture the *exact* query that's being executed and paste it into PHPAdmin to see if it succeeds.  What is that exact query?  What is the result of attempting to execute it?

Comment: I did not know about that capability of PHPAdmin. I am trying to test everything in there now but none of it makes any sense to me. I don't know PHP well enough to even know how to parse this out. It also does not appear to like any of the comments.At this point, I am ready to give up. I have spent two days trying to resolve this and I can't find the issue.